# t-sql single column result-set to 3 columns

Tags: sql-server

This is a bit of a weird question, and I know it would probably be easier to not do it in SQL, but it will make my life a lot easier.

Basically I have a single column result-set, and I need to turn that into 3 columns, not based on any criteria.

eg.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

into:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7
```

It will always be a fixed 3 column result I need in this case.

Currently I am using a cursor and inserting into a table variable, which seems a bit terrible. There must be a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain how this makes sense? Storing data in multiple columns that started out life in a single column is often a SQL "code smell". What determines which item goes in which column? Is there a column whose order matches the desired order of the columns? Why is it 3--and could it be 4 in the future?

Comment: I agree it is terrible, but it is a constraint of an existing system.
Basically we have some .NET code somewhere that will run a SP once for each row in this resultset, and use the 3 values as parameters for the SP. Yes it will always be 3 for this specific case.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I suggest you use ROW_NUMBER to assign each record the number 1,2, or 3, something like this: `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [AColumn])-1) % 3 AssignedColumn` then use various crosstab methods to crosstab it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table(n int)

insert @t(n) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

select [0],[1],[2]
from
(
    select n
    , (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by n) - 1) % 3 c
    , (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by n) - 1) / 3 r
    from @t
) x
pivot (max(n) for c in ([0], [1], [2])) p
```

Comment: With this solution, SQL Server sort rows twice.

Comment: Agreed that I use the `ROW_NUMBER()` code snippet twice above; however SQL's pretty intelligent at spotting things like that.  If you look at the query plan generated for your code & mine it's exactly the same; so it comes down to which the developer feels is simpler to maintain / personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but man is this an ugly requirement. This *really* belongs in the presentation tier, not in the sql.

```
WITH original As
(
    SELEZCT MyColumn, row_number() over (order by MyColumn) as ordinal
    FROM RestOfOriginalQueryHere
), 
Grouped As 
(
    SELECT MyColumn, ordinal / 3 As row, ordinal % 3 As col
    FROM original
)
SELECT o1.MyColumn, o2.MyColumn, o3.MyColumn
FROM grouped g1
LEFT JOIN grouped g2 on g2.row = g1.row and g2.col = 1
LEFT JOIN grouped g3 on g2.row = g1.row and g3.col = 2 
WHERE g1.col = 0
```